# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:tabLayout'

Tags: android, tabwidget

I would like to customize tab widget by replacing the style with my own style.
The item I am going to replace is as follow :

```
 <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator_holo</item>
```

But I got this error :
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:tabLayout'

I have set the parent style like this :

```
<style name="customTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TabWidget">
```

The Project build target : Android 4.0

I also have cleaned the project but the error still exits.
How to fix the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tabLayout` is a non-public attribute currently. Here's the bug tracking this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65832 If you want to customize TabWidget this way you might have to do it programmatically using [TabSpec.setIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(android.view.View)).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem.  At least part of the solution is to add the tabLayout attribute to res/values/attrs.xml.  Here is the definition of the TabWidget styles, copied from the android-16 platform (notice the tabLayout attribute at the end):

```
<declare-styleable name="TabWidget">
    <!-- Drawable used to draw the divider between tabs. -->
    <attr name="divider" />
    <!-- Determines whether the strip under the tab indicators is drawn or not. -->
    <attr name="tabStripEnabled" format="boolean" />
    <!-- Drawable used to draw the left part of the strip underneath the tabs. -->
    <attr name="tabStripLeft" format="reference" />
    <!-- Drawable used to draw the right part of the strip underneath the tabs. -->
    <attr name="tabStripRight" format="reference" />
    <!-- Layout used to organize each tab's content. -->
    <attr name="tabLayout" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Since you are overriding, you will also want to change:

```
 <item name="android:tabLayout">...
```

to:

```
 <item name="tabLayout">...
```

Comment: this solution does not seem to help me. Anything else I should do that was not mentioned by this answer?

Comment: I wrote that answer quite a while back.  Looking at it now, nothing comes to mind.  Sorry!

Comment: It is not solution. It is only allow compile code. nothing more. Android will not use custom attributes because do not know about it.