# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'middleBarArrowSize'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have given manually value to item in styles.xml

it is looking like below

[image]

```
<item name="middleBarArrowSize">16.0dip</item>
<item name="topBottomBarArrowSize">11.309998dip</item>
<item name="disableChildrenWhenDisabled">true</item>
```

also in some places

```
<item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
 <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
```

but in colors.xml I have declared value like

```
<color name="cardview_dark_background">#ff202020</color>
<color name="cardview_light_background">#fffafafa</color>
<color name="cardview_shadow_end_color">#03000000</color>
<color name="cardview_shadow_start_color">#37000000</color>
<color name="common_action_bar_splitter">#ffd2d2d2</color>
```

screenshot is like below

[image]

I have searched many site

[No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeHint'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256999/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-homehint)

[No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610974/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-colorprimary)

[No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:tabLayout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816779/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidtablayout)

[Android Studio : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099431/android-studio-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidac)

[Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio?rq=1)

but no on eis helpful for me

will any one suggest me why i am getting this error and what is the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works:

```
<item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<item name="middleBarArrowSize">16.0dip</item>
```

Is because [`cardBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor) is declared in the `android.support.v7.cardview` package, which your project will have a dependency on. This can easily be confirmed if you open up:

```
<sdk_path>/extras/android/support/v7/cardview/res/values/attrs.xml
```

Amongst others, you'll find:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CardView">
        <!-- Background color for CardView. -->
        <attr name="cardBackgroundColor" format="color" />
        ...
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Based on the code you've given, `middleBarArrowSize` hasn't been *declared* anywhere yet. In order to use a custom attribute, you have to declare it first (similar to above).

This process is explained [in the docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) and will result in something like this:

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MyCustomAttributes">
       <attr name="middleBarArrowSize" format="dimension" />
       <attr name="topBottomBarArrowSize" format="dimension" />
       <attr name="disableChildrenWhenDisabled" format="boolean" />
       <!-- add more here -->
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

After having done that, you should be able to use the declared attributes in your project.

> but in colors.xml I have declared value like (...)

There is a difference between *attributes* and *colors*. A color is a *value*, whereas an attribute is something you can *assign a value to* (i.e. a color, or a string, etc).

Comment: Thanks you so much for you awesome reply

Comment: excellect answer 1k+ views and not one upvote? so +1

Comment: @Hughzi: Oh well, sometimes karma's a b*tch. :) Appreciate the upvote!

Answer (score 1):

In case some resource not found for example

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0"
```

[image]

At this time first you check `values-v24` and your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0"
}
```

If your file name version and `dependencies api` version same then you can resolve this type of error easily.

For example

`com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0` is OK for `values-v24`  res folder